# Running Javascript from HTML data

Tags: javascript, c, v8

I have a c based application. It access web pages and gets html data, javascripts etc. The html data may contain javascript code and I need execute the javascript code.

I have integrated V8 (javascript engine used in chrome) to my c code.

I want to know what is the best logic to follow to execute javascript code.

One of the logic I think,

1. All the javascripts downloaded I will load / execute it with V8. This will make Javascript loaded into memory and there may not be any useful output.
2. When I get html data with *script* tag like  some javascript code , I will execute javascript code within *script* tag.

Is this right logic, or I am missing something. Or if you have a better suggestion, please share.

**EDIT1**

Basically my question is, what is the best logic that I need to follow when I scan through HTML data and execute javascript present in HTML data.

**EDIT2**

Lets take JMeter as an example. It gets HTML , Javascript data and executes javascript. I believe it does in Java. I need to do same thing in C. For that I have integrated V8 in my code. What I am lacking now, what is the best approach to scan through HTML data and execute javascript code.

Comment: What you're asking is really unclear.  What is the issue?

Comment: Sorry if my question is not clear. I adding more info to my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can’t really do it this way. V8 is only the JavaScript interpreter/ VM. Many of the expected APIs are part of the browser. For example, DOM, time, networking, etc, will not work. And the webpage you download most likely expects them too.

The correct solution is to include a full copy of chromium, or other browser backend.

Comment: Any idea how JMeter does it?

Comment: It doesn’t. https://jmeter.apache.org   Read the section “JMeter is not a browser”

Comment: Thanks for clarification on JMeter.